# CASE or IF statement in WHERE clause

Tags: sql

How can I use CASE statement or IF statement in WHERE clause ?
I am trying to apply a check on the basis of COUNT

```
SELECT * FROM sometable
WHERE CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sometable s WHERE SP = 2 AND sometable.id = s.id) > 2 THEN sometable.SP IS NOT NULL END
```

So basically if the count of rows is more than 1 it should apply IS NOT NULL condition else it should not.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.  Your code does not make sense.

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic suggests something like:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM (SELECT s.*,
             SUM(CASE WHEN sp = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY id) as cnt_2
      FROM sometable s
     ) s
WHERE cnt_2 <= 2 OR s.sp is not null;
```

That seems equivalent.  The logic doesn't seem particularly useful though.